# Bluetooth MAP (Message Access Profile) on iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I`m trying to create simple Bloetooth MAP Client under Windows. I prepared the code and at the beginning tested it only with Andoid phone and everything was working smoothly - receiving messages, notifications, sending messages. Problem appeared when I started testing iOS device - receiving messages and notifications are working without any issues, but I could not find a way to send message using MAP.

On some old posts I found information that Apple does not support sending messages via MAP, but on their website I found:

Message Access Profile (MAP 1.4)
This profile is compatible with iPhone 5s and later.

Message Access Profile allows devices to exchange messages. It's used to receive incoming message notifications on connected vehicles. iOS and iPadOS support these MAP functions on connected vehicles:

Receive incoming message notifications
Reply to incoming messages
Compose new messages
Browse message inbox
Mark messages as read

I`m a bit confused now. Has anybody any experience with MAP on iOS?
Appreciate any help/explanation in this topic.

Comment: If I had to guess the sources you are referring to likely predate Apple introducing support for the Message Access Profile.  As you observed Apple's support article detailing supported bluetooth profiles on iOS does include support for Message Access Profile 1.4.  That can be viewed here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102842.  Hope this helps!  Also, Microsoft did add to Phone Hub basic iMessage support with a connected iPhone using bluetooth, although I can't confirm which profile exactly.  https://www.theverge.com/2023/3/24/23654672/microsoft-phone-link-hands-on-imessage-ios